# Error expected expression before ")" token and C error - error: expected expression before ']' token

Tags: c, data-structures, deque

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 10;

int rradhe[MAX];
int koka = -1;
int bishti = -1;

void shto_djathas()
{
int element;

if ((koka == 0 && bishti == MAX -1 )||koka ==  bishti +1)
{
    printf("\nGjendje Overflow");
    getch ();int rradhe[MAX];
int koka = -1;
int bishti = -1;
    return;
}
if (koka == -1)
{
    koka = 0;
    bishti = 0;
}
else
    if (koka == MAX -1)
    bishti = 0;
else
    bishti = bishti + 1;
    printf ("\n Shtypni elementin qe doni te shtoni ");
    scanf ("%d", &element);
}

void main () {
    int c;
while(1){
printf("---------------------------");
printf("\nDetyre Kursi - Ivi Hysenbelli , Olsi Lala");
printf("\n 1 - Shtoni element ne rradhe"); // elementet do te shtohen nga e djatha
printf("\n 2 - Hiq element nga e djatha(Nga fillimi)");
printf("\n 3 - Hiq element nga e majta(Nga fundi)");
printf("\n 4 - Afisho rradhen");
scanf("%d",&c);
switch (c) {

case 1:
    shto_djathas();
    break;



}

}
}
```

I cant get why is showing me this error.

the error code is on lines
5.
13.
16.
27
i tried almost everything and read too many forums but i cant get why.
this is my first deque in c..im a newbie in c programming and i will really appreciate your help.
thanks in advance.

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: Loose the semicolon at the end of `#define MAX 10;`. The line numbers were a hint.

Comment: and try to accept some answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 10

int rradhe[MAX];
int koka = -1;
int bishti = -1;

void shto_djathas()
{
int element;

if ((koka == 0 && bishti == MAX -1 )||koka ==  bishti +1)
{
    printf("\nGjendje Overflow");
    getch ();int rradhe[MAX];
int koka = -1;
int bishti = -1;
    return;
}
if (koka == -1)
{
    koka = 0;
    bishti = 0;
}
else
    if (koka == MAX -1)
    bishti = 0;
else
    bishti = bishti + 1;
    printf ("\n Shtypni elementin qe doni te shtoni ");
    scanf ("%d", &element);
}

int main () {

    int c;
    while(true){
        printf("---------------------------");
        printf("\nDetyre Kursi - Ivi Hysenbelli , Olsi Lala");
        printf("\n 1 - Shtoni element ne rradhe"); // elementet do te shtohen nga e djatha
        printf("\n 2 - Hiq element nga e djatha(Nga fillimi)");
        printf("\n 3 - Hiq element nga e majta(Nga fundi)");
        printf("\n 4 - Afisho rradhen");
        scanf("%d",&c);

        if (c == 1)
            shto_djathas();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon from the macro definition

`#define MAX 10;` should be `#define MAX 10`

And read about why [not to use semicolon in the end of macro](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon).